# Data From TableviewController to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Passing data between a TableviewController to A UIViewController containing a TableView inside of , The tableview delegate where set with the UIViewcontroller . the name of the articlce was passed in the Viewcontroller but not the images .

Comment: If you log arrayofimages in viewDidLoad of the NewViewController, does it give what you expect? Does [object objectForKey:@"news_image"] return an array?

Comment: what do u mean @rdelmar

Comment: I mean log arrayofimages, NSLog(@"%@",arrayofimages) in viewDidLoad of NewViewController, and see what it gives you. Also, if you log [object objectForKey:@"news_image"] (in prepareForSegue) what does it give?

Comment: its null in the NewViewcontroller and inside of the prepare segue  @rdelmar

Comment: How about the log of [object objectForKey:@"news_image"] (in prepareForSegue)? Also, log destination in prepareForSegue.

Comment: its also null @rdelmar

Comment: And is destination also null?

Comment: Ok, I don't know how that's possible. destination is defined as segue.destinationViewController, and that has to return whatever you've hooked your segue to.

Comment: the strange thing is that the arrayofname that containts the newsname data was passed to the NewviewController

Comment: is the same code sir nothing new but NSlog @rdelmar

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to see, because what you're telling me makes no sense. If destination is null, the segue shouldn't have even worked, and it certainly shouldn't have passed the arrayofname properly.

Comment: destination.arrayofname=[object objectForKey:@"newsname"];, this line of code works

Comment: Apparently, object either does't have a key named "news_image", or the value for this particular object is null. Are you sure object has a "news_image" key?

Comment: news_image is a class in parse but there is a colunm where all images are saved its call "image"

Comment: what is that @HotLicks and also i am not passing data between Two viewcontrollers

Comment: Then why did you say "Passing data between a TableviewController to A UIViewController"???

Comment: the viewcontroller has a tableview inside of it too can you help me please take a look at my code i really need help @HotLicks

Comment: Your problem isn't passing the data. If destination.arrayofimages in prepareForSegue in nil, then your problem is getting the data out of  your Parse object.

Comment: so do you think i should the name of the colunm thats contains all the images but not the class right

Comment: I guess, but I haven't used Parse much, and I don't know how you set up your class.

Answer (score 0):

What is `PFImageView *imageView=(PFImageView *)[tableView viewWithTag:1]` suppose to do?

The cell you dequeued will not be in `tableView`, so if you want to set an image in that cell, you won't get what you want.

As a guess I think you would want `PFImageView *imageView=(PFImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1]`.